# Flurry Authentication & CSV downloads via cURL

Tags: php, curl, flurry, flurry-analytics

I'm trying to authenticate and download the Flurry event log via php & cURL.  The [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603460/download-flurry-event-log-using-curl#) by silkfire got me part of the way, but I'm still having trouble getting the download. I believe I've authenticated, but the download seems to return an error page instead of the file.  Here's the latest code I'm trying:

```
$post = array(
  'loginEmail'        => 'email',
  'loginPassword'     => 'pw',
  //'rememberMeCheckbox' => 'true',
  //'__checkbox_rememberMeCheckbox' => 'true',
  'struts.token.name' => 'token',
);

//$ckfile = tempnam("/tmp", "FLURRYCOOKIE");

$ch = curl_init('https://dev.flurry.com/secure/login.do');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, null);
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML(curl_exec($ch));

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);


$post['token'] = $xpath->query('//input[@name="token"]')->item(0)->getAttribute('value');


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://dev.flurry.com/secure/loginAction.do');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
//curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile );
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$login = curl_exec($ch);

$log_url = 'https://dev.flurry.com/eventsLogCsv.do?projectID=12345&versionCut=versionsAll&intervalCut=30Days&childProjectId=0&stream=true&direction=1&offset=0';
$ch = curl_init();
//curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $log_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
//print_r($data);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$destination = "/tmp/flurry_event_log.csv";
$file = fopen($destination, "w");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: Here's the main content of the response for $data:

```
    <div id="main">
    <!-- center -->
    <div id="centerColumn">
      <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
      <div class="fontSize" style="margin:50px;">
            <h2>Oops, an unexpected error has occurred.</h2>
            <br/><br/><br/>
            Please <a class="colorMediumBlue bold hover fontSize" href="/">go home</a> and try again.
            <br/><br/><br/>
            If you receive this same message more than once,
            please email <a class="colorMediumBlue bold hover fontSize" href="mailto:support@flurry.com">support@flurry.com</a> with details on how you arrived on this error page.
        <br/><br/>
        We apologize for this inconvenience and we will find a solution to this issue as soon as possible.
        <br/><br/>
        Sincerely,<br/>
        The Flurry Team
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line code to your first curl call:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookieFileName");
```

Then after you stored cookie data, use it on your second curl call with this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookieFileName");
```

And be sure cookies stored and you dont have any permission problem on /tmp/cookieFileName path or any path you desire.

I edited your code;

```
<?php

$post = array(
    'loginEmail' => 'mertizci@xxxxx.com',
    'loginPassword' => 'xxxxxxx',
    //'rememberMeCheckbox' => 'true',
    //'__checkbox_rememberMeCheckbox' => 'true',
    'struts.token.name' => 'token',
);
$ch = curl_init('https://dev.flurry.com/secure/login.do');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, null);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML(curl_exec($ch));

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$post['token'] = $xpath->query('//input[@name="token"]')->item(0)->getAttribute('value');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://dev.flurry.com/secure/loginAction.do');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
curl_exec($ch);

$log_url = 'https://dev.flurry.com/eventsLogCsv.do?projectID=12345&versionCut=versionsAll&intervalCut=30Days&childProjectId=0&stream=true&direction=1&offset=0';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $log_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
//print_r($data);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: mertizci, thanks for your quick response.  I tried your changes and I'm still getting a web page back for data and not the csv download.  I verified the permissions for the cookie file (they're wide open 777), so that shouldn't be an issue. I'll add the main content of the response page to my original post.

Comment: @joekrukosky can you try again with my code? i edited it.

Comment: Outstanding, that did it.  Mertizci I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @mertizci I have integrated above code snippet but it generates fatal error "Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object"