# Downloading Event Logs using the API

Tags: flurry

When downloading Event Logs, is it possible to get them using the API instead of downloading them via the Download CSV button on a web browser?

Is there an API for which it is possible among the URLs below?
https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/api/code/analyticsapi/

Also, if you plan to add it in the future, please let me know when it is scheduled for completion.

I appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no API for get Event Logs(raw data) as far as I know.

Workaround:

Downloading Event Logs CSV can be done something like
  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159305/perform-authentication-into-flurry-website-using-curl) with some additional touch. That implementation is for previous version.

After Flurry's renovation at 3/27/2017,

- Log in via `GET /auth/v1/session` with credentials
- Get '**flurry-auth-token**' from `GET /auth/v1/authorize`
- Call `GET ../eventLogCsv` with '**flurry-auth-token**' to download CSV

I'm a user of Flurry. And hope they support this feature via API soon.

Answer (score 1):

As of moment of writing, Flurry now provides `Raw Data Download` API, so you can retrive your raw event's data on a periodic basis (but within some limitations - time windows must be less than 1 month, data preparation takes some time, etc.)

Simplified workflow is following:

**1. Setup**

First of all, you must generate a Programmatic Token (discrabed here https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/api/code/apptoken/, process is straightforward, except that you'll need to create another user with different role in order to use this token)

**2. Making the Request**

Specify `startTime/endTime` for desired time window inside request (within other parameters):

```
curl -X POST   https://rawdata.flurry.com/pulse/v1/rawData
   -H 'accept: application/vnd.api+json'
   -H 'authorization: Bearer ~~YOUR TOKEN~~'
   -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
   -H 'content-type: application/vnd.api+json'
   -d '{"data": {
         "type": "rawData",
         "attributes": {
         "startTime": "1511164800000",
     "endTime": "1511251199000",
     "outputFormat": "JSON",
           "apiKey": "AAAA1111BBBB2222CCCC"
       }
     }
   }'
```

If your request was successful (`requestStatus` equals `Acknowledged` inside response body), save the `id` value from response.

**3. Checking for data preparation status**

Depending on complexity of your app and requested time window, data preparation make take about 30 minutes up to a few hours to be prepared.

You can check status by using:

```
curl -g https://rawdata.flurry.com/pulse/v1/rawData/26?fields[rawData]=requestStatus,s3URI
   -H ‘accept: application/vnd.api+json;’
   -H ‘authorization: Bearer ~~YOUR TOKEN~~’
   -H ‘cache-control: no-cache’
   -H ‘content-type: application/vnd.api+json;’
```

As soon as your data is ready, response will be following:

```
{
   "data":{
      "type":"rawData",
      "id":"26",
      "attributes":{
         "requestStatus":"Success",
         "s3URI":"https://flurry-rdd.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/26.JSON.gz?AWSAccessKeyId=AAAA1111BBBB2222CCCC&Expires=1513101235&Signature=h%2FChXRi5QwmvhUrkpwq2nVKf8sc%3D"
      }
   }
}
```

Save `s3URI` for next step.

**4. Retrieving Results**

Now you can retrieve archived raw data by using `s3URI`:

```
curl -O https://flurry-rdd.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/26.JSON.gz?AWSAccessKeyId=AAAA1111BBBB2222CCCC&Expires=1513039053&Signature=xbKNnTgpv1odAfVgPRLMyck8UnE%3D
```

Source: https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/rdd/